# Help with Taylor series problem

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

I am using maple to plot the graphs of e^e^x versus its truncated Taylor series around 0. For small values of x, the two graphs converge nicely, but once x<-3, my Taylor series loses control. Here is a graph of e^e^x in blue, versus the first 500 terms of its Taylor series.

[image]

and here is the same graph but with twice as many terms in the Taylor series.

[image]

Surely the Taylor series of e^e^x has an infinite radius of convergence so as I add infinitely many terms, it should converge nicely. Why is this happening to me!?

Answer (score 2):

For any particular $r$, the convergence is uniform on $|x| \le r$, but as
$r$ increases it may take more and more terms to get the remainder bounded by
a given $\epsilon$.

Here's a plot of the absolute value of the $n$'th term $|a_n (-3)^n|$ at $x = -3$ for 
$n$ up to $200$.  You get some very big terms (up to about $1.36 \times 10^7$) before things settle down.

[image]

For the $n$'th term at $x=-4$, the peak is even higher and shifted to larger $n$:

[image]

There are also numerical issues in computing a sum of very large terms that should almost cancel: you'll get a large roundoff error.

Comment: Ok so I just need to add an obscene amount of terms then. Thanks :)

Comment: ... and an obscene amount of numerical precision.

Comment: Take a look at the new graph I've posted. Does this not look suspicious, they are practically identical despite adding all the new terms. They both go haywire at the same point.

Comment: That supports the idea that a lot of what you're seeing is roundoff error.